# Is there a way of setting a property once only in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a way to allow a property in a C# object to be set once only. It's easy to write the code to do this, but I would rather use a standard mechanism if one exists.

```
public OneShot<int> SetOnceProperty { get; set; }
```

What I want to happen is that the property can be set if it is not already set, but throw an exception if it has been set before. It should function like a Nullable value where I can check to see if it has been set or not.

Comment: This smells for me, sorry. Why not pass the value in on a constructor? Also, are you going to provide feed back to the caller so they can check before setting the value, to ensure it hasn't been set?

Comment: Ideally I would pass it in the constructor, but I have to build the object up over a period of time. eg one record provides information A, the next record provides information B and C. Once I have a complete set of information, I then use this information to link all the records back together. I wanted a runtime mechanism to verify I only set values once, making them psuedo readonly!

Comment: And yes - it smells for me as well!

Comment: It only smells because you assume it smells. I needed this when a framework I was using called into an object that it instantiated and gave me no way at all to inject dependencies. So, I had my composition root push the container to a write once static property defined on that object.

Comment: C# 9.0 introduced with expressions for records. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There is direct support for this in the TPL in .NET 4.0;

(edit: the above sentence was written in anticipation of `System.Threading.WriteOnce<T>` which existed in the "preview" bits available at the time, but this seems to have evaporated before the TPL hit RTM/GA)

until then just do the check yourself... it isn't many lines, from what I recall...

something like:

```
public sealed class WriteOnce<T>
{
    private T value;
    private bool hasValue;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return hasValue ? Convert.ToString(value) : "";
    }
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!hasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException("Value not set");
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (hasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException("Value already set");
            this.value = value;
            this.hasValue = true;
        }
    }
    public T ValueOrDefault { get { return value; } }

    public static implicit operator T(WriteOnce<T> value) { return value.Value; }
}
```

Then use, for example:

```
readonly WriteOnce<string> name = new WriteOnce<string>();
public WriteOnce<string> Name { get { return name; } }
```

Comment: I was so busy polishing my own answer that I didn't notice you wrote (practially) the same darned thing.  I don't feel so special anymore.

Comment: Would you mind adding the direct support version of this (since we're way past .NET 4.0 already). I can't seem to find any information regarding this feature.

Comment: It is possible Marc was talking about https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh194820(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly no, I wasn't

Comment: @MarcGravell What exactly in the TPL enables this? `TaskCompletionSource<T>`?

Comment: What were you talking about then?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez in the original CTP of the parallel extensions framework (which was "current" when I wrote this, IIRC), there was a `WriteOnce<T>` type - *not* related to the dataflow bits. Not sure if this still exists or made it to RTM: but - it existed at time of writing. You can still find traces of them - [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/17bb93a1-73c4-473c-ae9b-62e8c7088310/lazyinitt-and-writeoncet-should-be-a-class?forum=parallelextensions), [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pedram/2008/06/02/coordination-data-structures-writeoncet/)

Comment: @RonnieOverby FYI ^^^

Answer (score 33):

You can roll your own (see the end of the answer for a more robust implementation that is thread safe and supports default values).

```
public class SetOnce<T>
{
    private bool set;
    private T value;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            if (set) throw new AlreadySetException(value);
            set = true;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(SetOnce<T> toConvert)
    {
        return toConvert.value;
    }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly SetOnce<int> toBeSetOnce = new SetOnce<int>();

    public int ToBeSetOnce
    {
        get { return toBeSetOnce; }
        set { toBeSetOnce.Value = value; }
    }
}
```

**More robust implementation below**

```
public class SetOnce<T>
{
    private readonly object syncLock = new object();
    private readonly bool throwIfNotSet;
    private readonly string valueName;
    private bool set;
    private T value;

    public SetOnce(string valueName)
    {
        this.valueName = valueName;
        throwIfGet = true;
    }

    public SetOnce(string valueName, T defaultValue)
    {
        this.valueName = valueName;
        value = defaultValue;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                if (!set && throwIfNotSet) throw new ValueNotSetException(valueName);
                return value;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                if (set) throw new AlreadySetException(valueName, value);
                set = true;
                this.value = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(SetOnce<T> toConvert)
    {
        return toConvert.value;
    }
}


public class NamedValueException : InvalidOperationException
{
    private readonly string valueName;

    public NamedValueException(string valueName, string messageFormat)
        : base(string.Format(messageFormat, valueName))
    {
        this.valueName = valueName;
    }

    public string ValueName
    {
        get { return valueName; }
    }
}

public class AlreadySetException : NamedValueException
{
    private const string MESSAGE = "The value \"{0}\" has already been set.";

    public AlreadySetException(string valueName)
        : base(valueName, MESSAGE)
    {
    }
}

public class ValueNotSetException : NamedValueException
{
    private const string MESSAGE = "The value \"{0}\" has not yet been set.";

    public ValueNotSetException(string valueName)
        : base(valueName, MESSAGE)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Only you're not setting this.set to true when you set the value... ;)

Comment: There we go now we are setting it to true

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that, but then started seeing other issues too.  I put a more "production ready" version at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: throwIfGet (in the first constructor) isn't defined anywhere

Comment: Also, the AlreadySetException under the set is called with two values even though the constructor only takes one parameter

Comment: Ouch on locking for a property get

Comment: Thanks for the code. You should put it up on GitHub/NuGet.

Answer (score 20):

### C# 9 has this feature build in. It is called [Init only setters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#init-only-setters)

```
public DateTime RecordedAt { get; init; }
```

Comment: this is not really the same, since it allows setting value only at initialization and does not create an exception, compilation error instead

Answer (score 11):

This can be done with either fiddling with flag:

```
private OneShot<int> setOnce;
private bool setOnceSet;

public OneShot<int> SetOnce
{
    get { return setOnce; }
    set
    {
        if(setOnceSet)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        setOnce = value;
        setOnceSet = true;
    }
}
```

which is not good since you can potentially receive a run-time error. It's much better to enforce this behavior at compile-time:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly OneShot<int> setOnce;        

    public OneShot<int> SetOnce
    {
        get { return setOnce; }
    }

    public Foo() :
        this(null)
    {
    }

    public Foo(OneShot<int> setOnce)
    {
        this.setOnce = setOnce;
    }
}
```

and then use either constructor.

Comment: I want there to be a run time error if I try to set it twice. Otherwise I would have created a constructor that sets a readonly member variable

Answer (score 5):

No such feature in C# (as of 3.5). You have to code it yourself.

Comment: Microsoft should provide such feature.

Comment: I'm not sure. If something should be set only once, then it probably should be a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 4):

As Marc said there is no way to do this by default in .Net but adding one yourself is not too difficult.

```
public class SetOnceValue<T> { 
  private T m_value;
  private bool m_isSet;
  public bool IsSet { get { return m_isSet; }}
  public T Value { get {
    if ( !IsSet ) {
       throw new InvalidOperationException("Value not set");
    }
    return m_value;
  }
  public T ValueOrDefault { get { return m_isSet ? m_value : default(T); }}
  public SetOnceValue() { }
  public void SetValue(T value) {
    if ( IsSet ) {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Already set");
    }
    m_value = value;
    m_isSet = true;
  }
}
```

You can then use this as the backing for your particular property.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take on this:

```
public class ReadOnly<T> // or WriteOnce<T> or whatever name floats your boat
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<T> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    public Task<T> ValueAsync => _tcs.Task;
    public T Value => _tcs.Task.Result;

    public bool TrySetInitialValue(T value)
    {
        try
        {
            _tcs.SetResult(value);
            return true;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void SetInitialValue(T value)
    {
        if (!TrySetInitialValue(value))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The value has already been set.");
    }

    public static implicit operator T(ReadOnly<T> readOnly) => readOnly.Value;
    public static implicit operator Task<T>(ReadOnly<T> readOnly) => readOnly.ValueAsync;
}
```

[Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/839798/64334) suggests the TPL provides this functionality and I *think* `TaskCompletionSource<T>` might have been what he meant, but I can't be sure.

Some nice properties of my solution:

- `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is an officially support MS class which simplifies the implementation.
- You can choose to synchronously or asynchronously get the value.
- An instance of this class will implicitly convert to the type of value it stores. This can tidy up your code a little bit when you need to pass the value around.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered readonly? http://en.csharp-online.net/const,_static_and_readonly

It's only available to set during init, but might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper for once inizialization
/// </summary>
public class WriteOnce<T>
{
    private T _value;
    private Int32 _hasValue;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _hasValue, 1, 0) == 0)
                _value = value;
            else
                throw new Exception(String.Format("You can't inizialize class instance {0} twice", typeof(WriteOnce<T>)));
        }
    }

    public WriteOnce(T defaultValue)
    {
        _value = defaultValue;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(WriteOnce<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IFoo {

    int Bar { get; }
}

class Foo : IFoo {

    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

class Program {

    public static void Main() {

        IFoo myFoo = new Foo() {
            Bar = 5 // valid
        };

        int five = myFoo.Bar; // valid

        myFoo.Bar = 6; // compilation error
    }
}
```

Notice that myFoo is declared as an IFoo, but instantiated as a Foo.

This means that Bar can be set within the initializer block, but not through a later reference to myFoo.

Answer (score 0):

The answers assume that objects that receive a reference to an object in the future will not try to change it.  If you want to protect against this, you need to make your write-once code only work for types that implement ICloneable or are primitives.  the String type implements ICloneable for example.  then you would return a clone of the data or new instance of the primitive instead of the actual data.

Generics for primitives only:
    T GetObject where T: struct;

This is not needed if you know that objects that get a reference to the data will never overwrite it.

Also, consider if the ReadOnlyCollection will work for your application.  an exception is thrown whenever a change is attempted on the data.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted and top-rated answers most directly answer this (older) question, another strategy would be to build a class hierarchy such that you can construct children via parents, plus the new properties:

```
public class CreatedAtPointA 
{
    public int ExamplePropOne { get; }
    public bool ExamplePropTwo { get; }

    public CreatedAtPointA(int examplePropOne, bool examplePropTwo)
    {
        ExamplePropOne = examplePropOne;
        ExamplePropTwo = examplePropTwo;
    }
}

public class CreatedAtPointB : CreatedAtPointA
{
    public string ExamplePropThree { get; }

    public CreatedAtPointB(CreatedAtPointA dataFromPointA, string examplePropThree) 
        : base(dataFromPointA.ExamplePropOne, dataFromPointA.ExamplePropTwo)
    {
        ExamplePropThree = examplePropThree;
    }
}
```

By relying on constructors, you can spray some Febreeze on the code smell, though it's still tedious and a potentially expensive strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I created a type which allows a value to be set on construction,
then after that the value can only be set/overridden once,
otherwise an exception is thrown.

```
public class SetOnce<T>
{
    bool set;
    T value;

    public SetOnce(T init) =>
        this.value = init;

    public T Value
    {
        get => this.value;
        set
        {
            if (this.set) throw new AlreadySetException($"Not permitted to override {this.Value}.");
            this.set = true;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(SetOnce<T> setOnce) =>
        setOnce.value;

    class AlreadySetException : Exception
    {
        public AlreadySetException(string message) : base(message){}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems to be the prime subject of all duplicate related post about setting only once a property, I post my custom solution here.

To be brief, I took advantage of source generator to automatically generate back-end code of `WriteOnce<T>` a-like. (mine is called `SettableNTimesProperty<T>` but have kind of same purpose).

This end up being used like following.

Lets say you have this DTO class :

```
internal class DTO
{
    int ID { get; init; }
    string Name { get; init; }

    public DTO(int id, string name = "Default_DTO_Name")
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

In order to make its properties settable only once instead of using `init`, modify your code this way :

```
internal partial class DTO : IDTO
{
    public DTO(int id, string name = "Default_DTO_Name")
    {
        ((IDTO)this).ID = id;
        ((IDTO)this).Name = name;
    }
}
```

and add this `interface`

```
using SetOnceGenerator;
public interface IDTO
{
    [SetOnce]
    int ID { get; set; }

    [SetOnce]
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to allow multiple `set`, up to `n` times maximum, use `[SetNTimes(n)]` attribute instead of `[SetOnce]`

You can check it [here](https://github.com/elTRexx/SetOnceGenerator).

Answer (score -2):

You can do this but is not a clear solution and code readability is not the best. 
If you are doing code design you can have a look at [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) realization in tandem with AOP to [intercept](http://www.delarou.net/weblog/PermaLink,guid,72bdda24-0357-4ed9-9f2d-a5d1c884a35b.aspx) setters. The realization is just 123 :)

Comment: That's why link-only answers are off-topic... the _intercept_ link is dead :-(