# Load property lazy loading

Tags: c#, vb.net, design-patterns, lazy-evaluation

I have a property which getter should load its value only the first time. The second time it returns the loaded value without loading it again:

```cs
private Object _MemberValue;

public Object MemberValue
{
    get
    {
        if(_MemberValue == null)
        {
            _MemberValue = LoadMember();
        }

        return _MemberValue;
    }
}
```

In VB.NET there is the `Static` keyword. With it you don't have to declare a class wide member.

```vb
Public Property MemberValue as Object
    Get
        Static value as Object = Nothing

        If (value is Nothing) Then
            value = LoadMember()
        End If

        Return value
    End Get
End Property
```

In C# there isn't such a keyword.

Are there better C# implementations of this problem or other patterns?

Comment: [Recommended reading why using `Static` is bad.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7475348/993547)

Comment: Check out the Lazy object

Comment: What is wrong with your first snippet btw?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's not wrong, but it feels like there is a better implementation for this.

Comment: related question on using the `Lazy<>` class.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847721/when-should-i-use-lazyt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are there better C# implementations of this problem or other patterns?

Probably not. You can use `Lazy<T>` as an replacement if you like, but basically it is the same as your first example. Using `Static` in VB.NET [has some serious drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7475348/993547), so I wouldn't use it either way.

If you prefer `Lazy<T>`, this is what I would use:

```
private Lazy<object> _MemberLazy = new Lazy<object>(LoadMember);

public object MemberValue
{
    get
    {
        return _MemberLazy.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah well, I guess I deserved the downvote since I tried to help you guys with your misunderstanding of VB.NET's `Static`...

Comment: Somebody's having a field day on this question. Clearly does not like the question nor the answers. +1 from me though.

Comment: I mark this as answer because it answers my concrete question.

Answer (score 4):

Your initial approach seems appropriate, I have never had reason to do something different. That said if your goal here is to avoid a class level field that could potentially be written to outside the getter, perhaps something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1592955/3194005) would work. There are a number of other ReadOnly, WriteOnce, SetOnce implementations that would also work similarly.

**ReadOnlyField.cs**

```
public class ReadOnlyField<T>
{
    private bool _frozen;
    private T _value;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        { 
            if (_frozen)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public void Freeze()
    {
        _frozen = true;
    }
}
```

**YourObject.cs**

```
public class YourObject
{
    private readonly ReadOnlyField<object> _someMember;

    public object MemberValue
    {
        get
        {
            if(_someMember.Value == null)
            {
                _someMember.Value = LoadMember();
                _someMember.Freeze();
            }

            return _someMember.Value;
        }
    }

    public YourObject()
    {
        _someMember = new ReadOnlyField<object>();
    }
}
```

It's not perfect. Unlike your VB.Net example; code outside of the getter could write to the field first, but at least you're protected from it being overwritten after Freeze is called.

Comment: I didn't vote but I would assume it's because it seems like you are duplicating what Lazy<T> does, which started in .NET 4

Comment: @the_lotus Lazy has its own limitations. The question is unclear and not realistic. Load could be a function of other variables and you could need to refresh from UI or other events..