# Initializing a readonly member variable with a default constructor in C#

Tags: c#, generics, readonly

I have a simple Factory implementation in my code. I'm aiming to have the constructed objects retain a reference to the factory that created them, so I have them wired up similar to this:

```
public class Factory {

    public T CreateObject<T>() where T : Foo, new() 
    {
        return new T() {
            parent = this
        };
    }
}

public class Foo {

    internal Factory parent;
    internal Foo() { }
}
```

This works as it reads, but I've been thinking that I probably want that `parent` variable so that it cannot be changed once it's set by the factory. However, if I declare it like `internal readonly Factory parent;`, then the factory can't set it's value anymore on construction.

I'd normally remedy this by providing a parametered constructor, but that kills the generic implementation, because AFAIK `where T : new()` implies a parameter-less constructor.

I may just be missing a few cogs with my C# chops, but what would be the best way to go about implementing something like this? (Or would it be better to just ditch the `readonly` and trust that the code won't be modifying `parent` in an unsafe manner --- `NullReferenceException`s come to mind --- ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think you can obtain exactly what you want, but you could make a property that is only assignable once and let the factory overwrite it. But I guess the user can always force an override with `new CreatingFactory`, but I think this makes it difficult and at least clearly shows your intention.

You could do something like below.

```
    class Foo
    {
        private Factory factory;

        public Factory CreatingFactory
        {
            get { return factory; }
            set
            {
                if (factory != null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("the factory can only be set once");
                }
                factory = value;
            }
        }
    }

    class Factory
    {
        public T Create<T>()
            where T : Foo, new()
        {
            T t = new T()
            {
                CreatingFactory = this
            };
            return t;
        }
    }
```

After having created it i searched and found an answer that is probably better than mine: [Is there a way of setting a property once only in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839788/is-there-a-way-of-setting-a-property-once-only-in-c)

Comment: The answer on the linked article would be perfect. It's a bit more code, but has better type safety than resorting to reflection. Thanks a bunch. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use reflection to set the field, this will work regardless of the `readonly` modifier:

```
public class Factory
{
    public T CreateObject<T>() where T : Foo, new()
    {
        T t = new T();
        t.GetType()
         .GetField("parent", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
         .SetValue(t, this);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually thinking somewhere along the lines of reflection as a fallback in case there was no way to make this work without having to resort to it. :D If no other viable answers come up, I'm marking yours as this question's answer. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I came up with an approach that replaces your generic type parameter with a `Func` that shows how to construct the `Foo` object and allows you to set the parent in the constructor.

```
public class Factory {
    private Func<Factory, Foo> creator;

    public Factory(Func<Factory, Foo> creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public Foo CreateObject()
    {
        return this.creator(this);
    }
}

public class Foo {
    internal readonly Factory parent;
    internal Foo(Factory parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

and then

```
public void Main() {
    Factory myfactory = new Factory(fact => new Foo(fact));
    Foo myfoo = myfactory.CreateObject();
}
```

Comment: I'm all for using lambdas in my code, but unfortunately in this case, my factory is implemented as a singleton as well. So unless I can get around having to add several more layers of complexity to get around that using `Func`s, it's not really worthwhile. Thanks though.