# Const set property in C#

Tags: c#, static, constants

I have a variable in a class which must have a `const` value.

```
private string query;
```

The value of `query` can be set only after constructor call. The class is not a `static` class so there cannot be a `Static Constructor` with the variable being `static readonly` like usual. I was wondering can something like below be achieved

```
private string Query { get; const set;}
```

or

```
private string Query { get; static readonly set;}
```

so that my purpose is solved.

Or

Can I declare the variable normally as

```
private string query;
```

and then in the constructor I can make the variable `query` as `const` while initializing, i.e., dynamically.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!!

Comment: Instead of using auto properties you could use a setter that only sets the value if there isn't already one set, but of course this would mean you'd need a backing field that could be set directly..

Comment: There is no feature built into the system to handle what you need, you need to write it yourself. Look into the [Freezable pattern](http://architects.dzone.com/news/practical-concurrency-patterns) (also sometimes called a Popsicle object)

Comment: Why does it have to be set after the constructor ?

Comment: A very strange requirement to begin with. But a non-static class _can_ have a static ctor. But could that really solve this?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Static is only going define if the value is the same across all instances or (without static) if the value is specific to each instance.  Being able to only set the value once is a completely different requirement.  As he says it must be set after the constructor in any case I would rule out a static ctor as a solution.  The requirements sound confused to me.

Answer (score 3):

A member *variable/field* can *not* be [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) if it's "set [only] *after* the constructor call". Neither `const` or `static` have any meaning in context of `set` - and less so than readonly, which still does *not* apply to properties.

> The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on *fields*. When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, *assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class*.

One solution is to use a non-auto property with an explicit backing field and to *honor read-only by contract*. Other approaches include using a different pattern, including accepting the value in the constructor.

```
class Foo {
    // Only allow this to be set ONCE after the constructor, BY CONTRACT
    private string _query;

    // No setter, can't assign "accidently"
    string Query {
        get {
            if (_query == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Query not set");
            return _query;
        }
        // Or maybe just:
        // get { return _query; }
    }

    // Call later on, BEFORE Query is used - but ONLY call once
    void BindQuery (string query) {
        if (query == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
        if (_query != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Query already set");
        _query = query;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can also use an auto property with a private setter. You can get away without the backing field.

Comment: @MarcelN. That may suffice if the property is normally consumed publicly - in this case it is still a private property, mirroring the initial question. However, "set only once" checks couldn't be used with *only* an auto-property/setter meaning `BindQuery` would have to remain because there is no write-through ability to the implicit field. Also, the a separate field makes any usages of `_query` outside of `BindQuery` an easily (by visual inspection)  detectable coding error.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging this answer...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/839798/342669

...you could

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly _query = new WriteOnce<string>();

    public string Query
    {
        private get { return _query.Value; }
        set { _query.Value = value; }
    }        
}
```