# C# constant property that can only be set once

Tags: c#

I continually find myself needing a constant that has to be declared outside of a method's scope but can only be assigned a value inside the method. The result is that I have to null-check the value within the method before I assign a value, but at that point I can't make the constant a constant.

Isn't there a native C# modifier that can handle this? If not, does it exist in similar languages? Why doesn't it exist in C#?

There's a somewhat similar post here: [Is there a way of setting a property once only in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839788/is-there-a-way-of-setting-a-property-once-only-in-c-sharp)

But it primarily focuses on null-checking with getters and setters

Comment: Sounds like you want a [`readonly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) property

Comment: Take a look at `readonly`. The limitation is you can only assign a value to it in the constructor.

Comment: That's not possible (in C#) on method-level. Only on class-level you could do something like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way of setting a property once only in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839788/is-there-a-way-of-setting-a-property-once-only-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5):

When you want to lazily initialize a value use a `Lazy` instance.  This allows you to set the `Lazy` instance in the constructor, meaning that the field can be `readonly`, but ensures that the method to create the object isn't called until it's needed, and that it can only ever initialize the value once.

Comment: Unless someone used the `new` keyword again.

Comment: @user3185569 That's still not initializing that field again.  That's just creating a new instance, which is exactly what you'd want to happen out of a `readonly` field.  It can be set once per instance, not once per application.  If you need the latter, you merely need to make it `static`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a class field that can only be set inside a method a method that you specify.

However, you can restrict that for a field that can be only set inside the constructor. The keyword for that in called `readonly`.