# How to implement properties which can be set only one time

Tags: c#

I want to implement some properties that can be set only one time.
I am aware of readonly but i want to be able to set the value from outside the class.

The situation is the following:
I have a class which i use as a key for some data i read from database. This key-class contains several properties.

My first idea was to make multiple constructors where i can set the properties like i need them but since "not set" is a valid state for most of these properties i soon had a bunch of constructors and i decided this is not the best way.

I can't make the properties with public setters because they are key information and it's no good to change them afterwards. So i need a way to set them once from outside the key-class because i don't want to make 20 slightly diffrent constructors for every case.

Is there some readonly-like easy to go method to do this or will i have to implement it myself?

Comment: This article is realated to WPF specifically but you might want to steal the idea of making a [freezable object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview).

Comment: Are you possibly talking about making your class singleton?

Comment: Builder Pattern? Maybe even with "Fluent API" ... like `KeyClass.WithPropA("someValue").WithPropC("someotherValue").Build()` ?

Comment: @Fildor My thoughts exactly. Can you put this with an explanation in an answer? Should I?

Comment: @hvd Go for it. I haven't got the time right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way of setting a property once only in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839788/is-there-a-way-of-setting-a-property-once-only-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Have a boolean property (Editable) in your ViewModel classes, default its value to true, when mapping data coming from the database set it to false.

Comment: @bradbury9 What tells you OP even has ViewModels?

Comment: @Fildor Nothing, thats why its a comment and its not posted as an detailed answer ;-) Anyway, other tecnologies could have a similar approach.

Comment: @Mac Singleton wont allow me to have multiple instances of this class, does it? I´ll need to have more than one instance.

Comment: @Mac No, singleton by definition relates to one single instance. I dont see how singleton could help out, If you do, please elaborate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As also commented by @Fildor, the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) may be appropriate here. You can set the properties on your builder class as often as you want, there is no harm in allowing multiple assignment there. But once you use that to build your class, then it's locked, then no more modifications are allowed.

```
class MyClass {
  internal MyClass(MyClassBuilder builder) {
     MyProp1 = builder.MyProp1;
     MyProp2 = builder.MyProp2;
     MyProp3 = builder.MyProp3;
  }
  public string MyProp1 { get; }
  public string MyProp2 { get; }
  public string MyProp3 { get; }
}

class MyClassBuilder {
  public string MyProp1 { get; set; }
  public string MyProp2 { get; set; }
  public string MyProp3 { get; set; }
  public MyClass Build() => new MyClass(this);
}
```

Usage: `new MyClassBuilder { MyProp2 = "abc" }.Build()`. Different APIs are also possible based on the same general idea.

Comment: If the OP uses some kind of mapper API (for example automapper) combined with this answer, the code would be pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

The builder patter by `hvd` is really nice, and it is what you should most likely use. However, here are my 2 cents. I like somewhat how JS works at times, and here I try to emulate it. This is basically using a dictionary as a configuration collection, containing the names of the properties and the values needed.

```
public class Key
{
    private readonly string Property1;
    private readonly string Property2;
    private readonly string Property3 = "!";

    public Key(Dictionary<string, object> config)
    {
        if (config == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var type = typeof(Key);
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (string name in config.Keys)
        {
            var field = fields.Where(f => f.Name == name).SingleOrDefault();
            if (field == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            field.SetValue(this, config[name]);
        }
    }

    public string GetValues()
    {
        return Property1 + Property2 + Property3;
    }
}
```

And you can use it as:

```
var key = new Key(new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "Property1", "Hi, " },
        { "Property2", "There" }
    }
);

Console.WriteLine(key.GetValues()); // Hi, There!
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to have properties with public setter and have a flag for each one, first time the setter is called set flag to `true` and return from the setter by checking the flag in subsequent calls.

If you have too many properties use a dictionary instead where you map properties to states (set/unset).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (basically what @SelmanGenc was suggesting):

```
public class Key {

private ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> _setProps = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();
private string _prop1;

public string Prop1 {

get { return _prop1; }
set { 
    if(!_setProps.ContainsKey(nameof(Prop1)){
        _setProps.Add(nameof(Prop1), true);
        _prop1 = value;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: @pere57 Really depends on a use case :)

Comment: @pere57 You could throw an exception in the `else` if you want so.

Answer (score 0):

Have a private property that know if its been set? 
something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private bool myValueSet = false;
   private string _myValue;

   public string MyValue
   {
      set {
        if (!myValueSet)
        {
          _myValue = value;
        }
      }
      get {
        return _myValue; 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is simillar to [zaitsman answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52147098/2265446), but his/her answer allows multiple properties (more easier to mantain)

Comment: @MarkRedman Yes, but you have no clue it has been ignored. You would have to read back and check ...

Comment: @pere57: I didn't see this as requirement in the original post.