# MVVM Connected Booleans

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm sure this is a silly problem, but i just can't figure it out right now.

Say i have a viewmodel with 3 boolean properties and they are connected somehow. So if i set bool1 = true, bool2/3 get set to false. If i set bool2 to false, something unrelated happens, if i set bool3 to true, bool1 gets set to true.

I just typed this out randomly, assume there is no stackoverflow exception.

My Problem is, how do i stop the bool2 onChange code from firing, if it got set by some other boolean?
They all chain off each other and i have no way to only fire the "bool 2 = false" without any logic in the setter or in an onChangeHandler firing too.

For now i got around this by just creating another flag in my viewModel "AllowChangeFiring" and wrap all my logic like this.

```
if(AllowChangeFiring){
  AllowChangeFiring = false;
  bool 2 = false;
  ...
}
AllowChangeFiring = true;
```

But this can't be the way to deal with this situation? I must be missing something obvious right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839788/is-there-a-way-of-setting-a-property-once-only-in-c-sharp

Comment: *I must be missing something obvious right?* yes, the fact that without changing setter it is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve is possible if you don't use the setters of the properties, but the private variables behind the properties. Via that, you won't have any side effects.

```
private bool _b1;
public bool B1
{
 get
  {
  return _b1;
  }
set
 {
  _b1 = value;
  if(value)
  {
   _b2 = false;
   _b3 = false;
  }
 }
}

private bool _b2;
public bool B2
 {
 get
  {
  return _b2;
  }
 set
  {
  _b2 = value;
  if(!value)
   {
   SomethingUnrelated();
   }
  }
 }

private bool _b3;
public bool B3
 {
 get
  {
  return _b3;
  }
 set
  {
  _b3 = value;
  if(value)
   {
   _b1 = true;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: ah yea that can work. Im using a mvvm framework where the private variables arent necessary, so i kinda forgot about it.